# Record Linkage In Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, record-linkage

How to achieve recordlinkage functionality in Pyspark ???
I want to do a similarity check between Dataset1 Name and Dataset 2 Name.

Please help suggest me if any library available for pyspark.

I try with the recordlinkage library of pyhton but it is working with pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

[Splink](https://github.com/moj-analytical-services/splink) is the best option that I know of.